# Regular expression for avoid repeated consecutive chars, but excluding one specific char

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I am learning a lot of Regex with Python, and I am struggled with a regex for allow test cases where doesn't have consecutive 4 or more repeated chars, I have found easy solutions in Internet but I need evaluate the repeated chars excluding the "-" char, for example:

```
bic-hota  // Valid
bichota  // Valid
bichota1234 // Valid
bich222ota // Valid, sequence "222" with length of 3 is allowed 

bichota2222 // Invalid because have "2222" and isn't allowed length of 4 or more
bichota22-22 // Invalid because have "2222" (ignore the '-') and isn't allowed length of 4 or more
```

In the last test case, you can see the sequence "22-22", I need ignore the "-" between the sequence for validate whole the sequence, and I have searched about how to solve this and I have use the Non-capture group `(?:-?)` but this doesn't works :(

```
^(?![\w]*([\w])(?:-?)\1{3,})[\w-]+$
```

What is wrong with my regex and how to fix it?

Test cases: https://regexr.com/6p0ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?!.*(\w)(?:-?\1){3}).+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZu66K/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `.*`: Match any length of characters
  - `(\w)`: Match a character and capture in group #1
  - `(?:-?\1){3}`: Match optional `-` followed by back-reference to group #1. Repeat this group 3 times.
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `.+`: Match 1+ of any characters

---

To allow only word characters and hyphens use:

```
^(?![\w-]*(\w)(?:-?\1){3})[\w-]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Or match **the unwanted**:

```
[^\w-]|(\w)(-?\1){3}
```

- `[^\w-]` a character that is [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a *word character* or hyphen
- `(\w)(-?\1){3}` four [repeated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `\w` with [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) hyphen in between
- `|^$` can be further attached for [empty string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) positives if needed ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/utfpgE/1))

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OLDlo6/1) (the `\n` is just used for the multiline demo)

This way the matched part could even be displayed in some fail-message.